# Can't install libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to install LibGDX for java.
I have been searching for 2 two days but didn't find anything yet.
(I am a newbie so I was thinking maybe I can improve myself with this library)
Really need help here.

[image: libGDX project setup screenshot]

[image: libGDX project setup screenshot2]

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
*What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  > Could not download uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:uast:145.597.3)
   > Could not get resource 'https://center.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/uast/145.597.3/uast-145.597.3.jar'
      > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

*Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.Run with --info or debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I have the `uast-145.597.3.jar` which downloaded online both don't know what to do with it.